# Pointer storing same address for different variables in C++

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the pointer I created is storing same address i.e `0x6dfee4` in both of the following programs.

First program:

```
int no1 = 100, no2 = 2;
int * p = &no1;

cout << "Value : " << *p << endl;
cout << "Address : " << p << endl;
```

Second program:

```
int no1 = 100, no2 = 2;
int * p = &no2;    // <----- This is different from the first program.

cout << "Value : " << *p << endl;
cout << "Address : " << p << endl;
```

But it gives a different result if I add following statements right after declaration and initiliization of the variables:

```
cout << &no1 << endl;
cout << &no2 << endl;
```

Why is that?

Comment: How did you compile this? It seems likely that in both cases, the unused variable is optimized out and doesn't even exist.

Comment: "_I don't know where the problem is in my code._" Why do you think there is a problem? What does it matter what the address happens to be? How can you be sure you always happen to get those results? What is the address of _another_ pointer variable holding the address of the other `int` if you try that? What does any of this matter in such a trivial program anyway? "_But it gives perfect result if..._" What is "perfect" about that? How do you know what a good/bad result is? (as defined by the language and/or practical usefulness, not just naive expectations)

Comment: please provide a [mre], at a guess you aren't using one of the variables so the compiler optimises it away

Comment: Don't assume that variables will be in memory. That is the back-up location where they are forced to go under some circumstances, including if you take the address.

Comment: You should have no expectation that the address of an object remains the same across multiple executions of your code or multiple executions of a given function (for function local objects). All you know is that the address of an object doesn't change during it's lifetime.

Comment: If you don't use a variable the compiler is free to get rid of it.  That is most likely what you are seeing.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not in this code by in your expectations

Comment: @AlanBirtles you were right I tested different situations and it is optimised by the compiler whenever I don't use it.

Comment: Until now I thought that a variable stores space in memory if you just create it doesn't matter if you use it or not.

Comment: What is it that you're doing that requires you to care about this?

Comment: @AhmadGhani That assumes a very inefficient and literal translation of your program. Reading about what optimising compilers can do, so long as they preserve the semantics of the language's "abstract machine", might blow your mind! ;-)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I am a teenager and started learning C++. This part just confused me. That's it. ;)

Comment: I would recommend focussing on far higher-level concepts when learning a language. Most C++ programmers should never need to print the address of something (unless they're debugging, but that's very different), and they certainly shouldn't need to care what that address is or whether it differs among runs.

Comment: @underscore_d I don't know how programmers work and what is necessary for them to do and what not. I did this just to clear my concept so that it doesn't make a fuss in future ;)

Comment: This 3 votes experiment has to stop. Bad closures are an epidemic. This question is not asking to fix anything, how can it be close for this reason? It's asking for an explanation of an observed behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the favour! BTW I have got the answer and I think anyone who will check this questions, can get the answer from the previous comments and answer. Sorry for bad English, hope you can understand what I want to say. Thanks again for this favour!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unused variable is not allocated storage space by the compiler.

In your first code, `no2` is not used, so it is not allocated space, only `no1` has space allocated, on address 0x6dfee4.

In your second code, `no1` is not used, so it is not allocated space, only `no2` has space allocated, on the same address 0x6dfee4, because `no2` is the only active variable with space allocated, similar to `no1` in the first code.

Note that the address allocation is compiler and OS dependent.

But, when you add `cout << &no1 << endl; cout << &no2 << endl;`, 
both `no1` and `no2` are used and have space allocated at different addresses, producing your expected result.

EDIT: Precisely speaking, even if a variable is used, it does not always have memory space allocated. It does in this code, because the existence of the `&` operator, which requires that the variable has a memory address during the variable's lifetime.

Comment: That is the proximal/practical reason, but it's almost less interesting than the more general answer: Even with functionally identical code and optimisations (or lack thereof, with which we might not observe the same results), there is no reason to expect that particular address, nor the same address, nor the same stack base, etc., etc. - even between invocations of an identical program.

Comment: Variables are not "allocated storage in compiler". Besides, the fact that it's used or not cannot have an influence on the object's address.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar No, but it can influence whether the object *gets* an address, and if it doesn't, another object that *is* used might *happen* to get that address in a slightly different program... which is what we saw here. So, true, but uninteresting.

Comment: When the variable address is taken, it must have storage so the address exists.

Comment: @underscore_d - using the `&` operator actually requires the object to have an address as long as that object's lifetime has not yet passed.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar ...which is precisely what the answerer and I are both saying...

Comment: If an object exists, it occupies a region of storage: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#1.sentence-3

Comment: @NathanOliver This storage is not necessary in memory, without `&` operator. It could be in register file

Comment: @NathanOliver Compiler is allowed to create output (machine code), which behaves *as-if* the variable occupies a region of storage. If it does not alter the observable behavior of the C code (debugger, which has access to the machine code and actual memory contents may see difference), the variable does not even need to exist in compiler output.